# Deleted EFI partition & "critical software update is required for your mac but an error was encountered" re-install EFI or Touchbar?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar, efi

So I've made the stupid mistake of deleting the EFI partition when reinstalling my 2016 MacBook Pro with TouchBar. I now get an error when reinstalling the MacOs "a critical software update is required for your mac but an error was encountered" I believe this is linked to the TouchBar not having the drivers/software needed or being installed.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to re-create/re-install the EFI partition, if so how?
2. Is there any software I can download to get my touchbar installed/working.
3. Is there a cloned image I can download to re-install the drivers/software of the EFI partition.
4. Is there any other know way to get the touchbar installed.

I've read on different forums that going to the Apple store and connecting to their network either via WiFi or ethernet might work or getting someone at the Apple store to run the MRI software might fix it.

So far I've tried the following:

Frest install of MacOs via internet recovery both to the original OS and latest os. 
Reset the NVRAM
Reset the SMC
Reformatted the drive back to journaled and then APFS

I'm running out of options...

I'm hoping someone out there might be able to shine a light on my situation or can think of something I haven't yet tried.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Reinstall the current macOS right over top of the one that is there now. That *usually* fixes that sort of (and other) issues. And while that reinstall should preserve all apps and data, do have a current backup, just in case...

Comment: Hi Steve, I've tried that. Apple tech support have advised me to bring it in for repair. I've been on the phone with them for over an hour and they just asked me to do the stuff Ive already tried. I've just tried a time machine backup and that didn't resolve the issue. It seems crazy that there aren't drivers or software you can manually download. More head scratching I guess...